# Dynamics Nav Control Add-in supported internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dynamics-nav, dynamics-nav-2013

I want to use the webgl in my add-in, so I need the IE 11 support. I've found that in temporary add-in's files (which are creating when the RTC client is starting) is line:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8; IE=9; IE=10">
```

which blocks the IE 11 support.

Is there any chance to change this meta data? Add the IE=11 line?

I've got Dynamics Nav 2013 and 2015, Windows Server 2012 R2 witch Internet Explorer 11, so I don't know why add-in doesn't support IE11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm Sorry, currently there is no Support from NAV2013/R2 or NAV2015 for IE11.

- [NAV 2013 Web Limitations R2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301054(v=nav.71).aspx):

> Supported:
>   Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008, and Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7, Windows 8, Windows Server 2008, and Windows Server 2012 (32-bit or 64-bit editions).

- [NAV 2015 Web Limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd301054(v=nav.80).aspx#NavApps):

> Supported browsers
>   Internet Explorer 10.
>   Google Chrome 36.0 for Windows.
>   Mozilla Firefox 31.0 for Windows.
>   Safari 7.1 on iOS (iPad).
>   Safari 7.0 on OSX.

---

Funny by the Way is, that the Tablet Client only by IE11 supported is.

Hope so, it will come soon.

Looking forward for the next Cumulative Updates.

Answer (score 0):

I've been investigating this very thing, and what I found is the Web Browser control that it I think it is using (Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.WinForms.WebBrowserForNavigation) doesn't have a problem running as IE11. (It may not be officially supported but when has that ever stopped us...)

So, what you can do is redirect your page to one with the right headers and that will support webGL. e.g.

```
window.parent.location.href = 'https://get.webgl.org/';
```

Note: your code is sitting in an iframe, so you have to redirect the parent which also has the headers you don't want. This works for me.

Next step is to get the "corrected" header page generated with the rest of the Add-in files and get the extensibility interactions working back and forth to NAV. It's a bit ugly but I've managed to get the basics working...

**--- EDIT 17/09/2015 ---**

Oops, I've just realised this is a bad bad idea! This will break the NAV Web Client because it doesn't structure its iframes/divs in the same way as the Web Browser control on the Windows Client.

Instead I'm opening a child window using this code

```
childWindow = window.open(Microsoft.Dynamics.NAV.GetImageResource('ChildWindow.htm'), 'child', "width=500, height=500, location=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, status=no, toolbar=no");
```

For more info about this see my blog:
https://geeknikolai.wordpress.com/2015/09/17/how-to-include-non-image-resources-with-dynamics-nav-javascript-add-ins